# React component loads data twice on moving back-and-forth between tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-state, react-state-management

For some reason my React component seems to remember its old state when going to another tab and back again, instead of reloading completely.

Basically when I click on the "Create" tab in my navbar and back to the "Board" tab data is populated twice instead of once, see image below. When going back the Board component `this.state` has two of each `taskIds`, as if it the component state still had the data from the initial page load when loading again. I have a React component looking like this:

[image]

```
const columnOrder = ['todo', 'in-progress', 'in-review', 'done']
const EMPTY_COLUMNS = {
  'todo': {
    id: 'todo',
    title: 'TODO',
    taskIds: []
  },
  'in-progress': {
    id: 'in-progress',
    title: 'In Progress',
    taskIds: [],
  },
  'in-review': {
    id: 'in-review',
    title: 'In Review',
    taskIds: []
  },
  'done': {
    id: 'done',
    title: 'Done',
    taskIds: []
  }
};

export class Board extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onLoadEpic = this.onLoadEpic.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            columnOrder: columnOrder,
            columns: {
                'in-progress': {
                    id: 'in-progress',
                    title: 'In Progress',
                    taskIds: [],
                },
            // ...more columns similar to above
            },
        };
    
    // Load state data on mount
    componentDidMount() {
        loadEpic(arg1, arg2);
    }

    // Async function loading items from DB and formatting into useful columns
    async loadEpic(arg1, arg2) {
        axios.get(...)
            .then((response) => {
                let data = response.data;
                let newTasks = {};
                let newColumns = EMPTY_COLUMNS;
                
                data.taskItems.forEach(function(item) {
                   let id = item.id.toString();
                   newColumns[item.status]["taskIds"].push(id);
                   newTasks[id] = {
                       ...item,
                       id: id
                   }
                });
                this.setState({
                    tasks: newTasks,
                    columns: newColumns
                });
            })
    }

    render() {
        // Prints ["7"] on initial load and ["7", "7"] after going back and forth
        console.log(this.state.columns["in-progress"].taskIds);
        return (
          // Simplified, but this is the main idea
          <Container>
          <DragDropContext  onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
              {
                  this.state.columnOrder.map((columnId) => {
                      const column = this.state.columns[columnId]
                      const tasks = column.taskIds.map(taskId => this.state.tasks[taskId]
                      return (
                          <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks}/>
                      )
                  }
              }
          </DragDropContext>
          </Container>
        )
    }

}
```

and an App.js with Routing looking like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render () {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Board} />
        <Route exact path='/create' component={Create} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out: it's the `EMPTY_COLUMNS` constant that is bugging out. When the component is re-rendered, the same `EMPTY_COLUMNS` object is referenced - so the constant is being appended to. Instead, I should make a copy of the empty columns:

```
// Before - same object is being appended to, doesn't work
let newColumns = EMPTY_COLUMNS;
// After - create a deep copy of the constant, does work
let newColumns = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(EMPTY_COLUMNS));
```

Comment: `let newColumns = EMPTY_COLUMNS` is going to create a shallow copy, where the array is a new array but the elements of that array are reference to the same objects that are in `EMPTY_COLUMNS`, so you are unintentionally mutating them.